# Understanding and using Symlinks

Tags: directory, symlink

I have a bit of a situation with a virtual server running some RHEL distro. The server is hosted on a Win2008 server via VMPlayer 
[image: uname]

When it was created the initial partitions were set incorrectly. /dev/hda1 has 6GB space and the /dev/hda6 has nearly 50GB

[image: dfah]

As you can see, they're running out of space and I can't resize the partitions. Most of the space is used by their SQL database and internal website. I've been told I can move everything to the hda6 partition and use symlinks to point to it. I've not tried using symlinks before and my initial tests were unsuccessful.

How about using symlinks on an entire directory? or is there a better way to go about this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Symlinks to a directory work just fine, what problem are you having? This question doesn't seem to ask any questions at all..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're linking the full path of the source. So ln -s /home/user/docs/file.txt, not ln -s docs/file.txt.

If that's not your problem then you'll have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I would copy all partitions to a external drive. Then recreate the partitions the way you want. Then put the data in the partitions that you want them in. Then boot to live cd or usb and edit fstab to reflect the new partition uuids'.

or

I would shrink the hda6 partition that has room. Create a new one, copy the hda1 partition to the new one. Then wipe hda1 and move hda6 to hda1. Then wipe hda6 then resize the new partition to fill the drive.